# I'm prepare to study react native,but meet some problems when installing the environment

Tags: node.js, react-native, nvm

after installed the nvm,I ready to install the node,but when I print the code:"nvm install node && nvm alias default node",it results in "Version 'node' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions."

```
lotusdeMacBook-Pro:~ hfr$ nvm install node && nvm alias default node
Version 'node' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
```

actually,my Mac has installed the node in another way, but then I can't install react-native-cli. The problems is:

```
lotusdeMacBook-Pro:~ hfr$ npm install -g react-native-cli
npm WARN engine react-native-cli@0.1.10: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.33","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/hfr
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hfr/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I don't know why. I need your help,thanks ahead.

Comment: right now,I uninstalled the node,and then try to use this "nvm install node && nvm alias default node" to install the node,but it results in "
Version 'node' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions." ,and then enter "nvm ls-remote",it results in "N/A"........

Answer (score 0):

Try `nvm install v5.6.0 && nvm alias default v5.6.0`.

The `node` in the nvm docs is a placeholder for a node version.

Regarding your other node installation, you should probably uninstall it, when you have no other use for it, as it is outdated.

Comment: en,the installed node was installed by "nvm install v5.6.0". For I can't use "nvm install node && nvm alias default node" this code to install node ,so I used "nvm install v5.6.0"to install and successed as u see. But now,the problem is  I can't install react-native-cli.

Comment: what do `node --version` and `npm -v` print out?

Comment: lotusdeMacBook-Pro:~ hfr$ node --version
     -bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
     lotusdeMacBook-Pro:~ hfr$ npm -v
     -bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory

Comment: does `nvm -v` print out something usefull?

Comment: try `nvm install v5.6.0` again and tell me the result.

Comment: the result is:Version 'v5.6.0' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.

Comment: that is weird, maybe try to update your nvm? the `nvm install v5.6.0` just works fine for me